# Protein Chemical Shift Prediction processing

Tags: python

I have 2 scripts, one is a tkinter GUI script where the user gives specific inputs, the 2nd script takes those inputs, does some modification, and then sends it back to the GUI script to be written/results printed. However, in dealing with multiple user inputs, the entries for the functions started getting longer and longer, and uglier. As you'll see in the GUI script, when I use the function I imported, it has 7 entries which make it quite long. Is there a better way to call user inputs from one script to another?

```
#GUI Script (NOTE: I'm not posting all the global and input functions, since they are basically the same thing. Don't want to be reptitious)
#basic tkinter setup root=tk.Tk() with the loop and everything setup

#globals where filenames and directories to files are saved, to be called on in the functions
sparta_file=()
sparta_directory=()
seq_file=()
seq_directory=()
#browse options to choose files
def input_file():
    fullpath = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, title='Choose a file')
    global sparta_directory
    global sparta_file
    sparta_directory=os.path.dirname(fullpath)
    sparta_file= os.path.basename(fullpath)
    label2=Label(root,text=fullpath).grid(row=0,column=1)

def input_seq():
    fullpath = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, title='Choose a file')
    global seq_file
    global seq_directory
    seq_directory=os.path.dirname(fullpath)
    seq_file= os.path.basename(fullpath)
    label3=Label(root,text=fullpath).grid(row=1,column=1)
#All the user inputs are designed more or less the same, user browses, clicks on file, and files directory and filename are saved as globals. 

#function that will be run to use user inputs, modify them, and then write modifications
def sparta_gen_only():
        from sparta_file_formatter import check_sparta_file_boundaries
        os.chdir(save_directory)
        with open(save_file_sparta,'w') as file:
            for stuff_to_write in check_sparta_file_boundaries(seq_file,seq_directory,mutation_list1,mutation_list2,sparta_file,sparta_directory,seq_start):
                file.write(stuff_to_write+'\n')
```

So right off the bat, you can see the exact issue I'm having (check_sparta_file boundaries has a lot of inputs).

```
#2nd sparta_file_formatter
import re
import os



def create_seq_list(seq_file,seq_directory,seq_start):
    os.chdir(seq_directory)
    amino_acid_count=(0+seq_start)-1
    sequence_list=[]
    with open(seq_file) as sequence_file:
        for amino_acid in sequence_file:
            stripped_amino_acid=amino_acid.strip().upper()
            for word in stripped_amino_acid:
                amino_acid_count+=1
                sequence_list.append(str(amino_acid_count)+word)
    return sequence_list

def format_sparta(sparta_file,sparta_directory):
    os.chdir(sparta_directory)
    sparta_file_list1=[]
    proline_counter=0
    with open(sparta_file) as sparta_predictions:
        for line in sparta_predictions:
            modifier=line.strip().upper()
            if re.findall('^\d+',modifier):
                A=modifier.split()
                del A[5:8]
                del A[3]
                A[0:3]=["".join(A[0:3])]
                joined=" ".join(A)
                proline_searcher=re.search('\BP',joined)
                if proline_searcher != None:
                    proline_counter+=1
                    if proline_counter<2:
                        proline_count=re.search('^\d+',joined)
                        sparta_file_list1.append(f'{proline_count.group(0)}PN'+' 1000'+' 1000')
                    else:
                        if proline_count == 4:
                            proline_count=re.search('^\d+',joined)
                            sparta_file_list1.append(f'{proline_count.group(0)}PHN'+' 1000'+' 1000')
                            proline_counter=0
                sparta_file_list1.append(joined)
    return sparta_file_list1

#Each function the entries get longer and longer as they start using the outputs of the previous functions
def add_mutation(mutation_list1,mutation_list2,sparta_file,sparta_directory):
    sparta_file_list2=[]
    if mutation_list1==() or mutation_list2==():
        for amino_acids in format_sparta(sparta_file,sparta_directory):
            sparta_file_list2.append(amino_acids)
    else:
        for mutations,mutations2 in zip(mutation_list1,mutation_list2):
            for amino_acids in format_sparta(sparta_file,sparta_directory):
                if re.findall(mutations,amino_acids):
                    splitting=amino_acids.split()
                    mutation=re.sub(mutations,mutations2,splitting[0])
                    mutation_value=re.sub('\d+.\d+',' 1000',splitting[1])
                    mutation_value2=re.sub('\d+.\d+',' 1000',splitting[2])
                    mutation_replacement=mutation+mutation_value+mutation_value2
                    sparta_file_list2.append(mutation_replacement)
                else:
                    sparta_file_list2.append(amino_acids)
    return sparta_file_list2

def filter_sparta_using_seq(seq_file,seq_directory,mutation_list1,mutation_list2,sparta_file,sparta_directory,seq_start):
    sparta_file_list3=[]
    sparta_comparison=create_seq_list(seq_file,seq_directory,seq_start)
    for aa in add_mutation(mutation_list1,mutation_list2,sparta_file,sparta_directory):
        modifiers=aa.strip()
        splitter=modifiers.split()
        searcher=re.search('^\d+[A-Z]',splitter[0])
        compiler=re.compile(searcher.group(0))
        sparta_sequence_comparison=list(filter(compiler.match,sparta_comparison))
        if sparta_sequence_comparison != []:
            sparta_file_list3.append(aa)

    return sparta_file_list3


def check_sparta_file_boundaries(seq_file,seq_directory,mutation_list1,mutation_list2,sparta_file,sparta_directory,seq_start):
    temp_list=[]
    temp_counter=0
    sparta_filtered_list=filter_sparta_using_seq(seq_file,seq_directory,mutation_list1,mutation_list2,sparta_file,sparta_directory,seq_start)
    for checker in sparta_filtered_list:
        temp_modifier=checker.strip()
        temp_split=temp_modifier.split()
        temp_finder=re.search('^\d+',temp_split[0])
        temp_list.append(temp_finder.group(0))
        temp_counter+=1
        if temp_counter==5:
            if int(temp_finder.group(0))==int(temp_list[0]):
                break
            else:
                del sparta_filtered_list[0:4]
                break
    if len(sparta_filtered_list)%6 != 0:
        del sparta_filtered_list[-5:-1]

    return sparta_filtered_list
```

Edit:

In terms of exactly what sparta is and what my code is doing. I won't go into too much detail regarding sparta, outside of it is a text file with information we want. This is the format:

```
REMARK SPARTA+ Protein Chemical Shift Prediction Table
REMARK  All chemical shifts are reported in ppm:
....

   3    Y   HA     0.000     4.561     4.550     0.018     0.000     0.201
   3    Y    C     0.000   175.913   175.900     0.021     0.000     1.272
   3    Y   CA     0.000    58.110    58.100     0.017     0.000     1.940
   3    Y   CB     0.000    38.467    38.460     0.011     0.000     1.050
   4    Q    N     3.399   123.306   119.800     0.179     0.000     2.598
...
```

We only care about the lines with the numbers, so I use a regex search to only extract that. Now the info I want is the first 3 columns, with the 4 column. I want each data formatted `3YHA 4.561` (2nd function). Now every number should have 6 values associated with it, those that are P, will only have 4, so I add 2 extra values (you may note in the above, the format is HA,C,CA,CB,etc. So I add the values so the format of P is N,HA,C,CA,CB.

Sometimes the user will wish to change a specific letter (mutation). So they indicate which letter, the number, and what to change it to (3rd loop).

Finally, these files can sometimes have extra info we don't care about. The user specifies the range of info they want by using a seq file (1st and 4rd loop).

As stated, every letter should have 6 values. However, the first letter will always have 4. The last letter will also only have 5. So these need to be removed (loop 5).

Here is some sample input files as examples:

```
seq_number=1
#seq.txt
MSYQVLARKW
#sparta_pred.tab
   3    Y   HA     0.000     4.561     4.550     0.018     0.000     0.201
   3    Y    C     0.000   175.913   175.900     0.021     0.000     1.272
   3    Y   CA     0.000    58.110    58.100     0.017     0.000     1.940
   3    Y   CB     0.000    38.467    38.460     0.011     0.000     1.050
   4    Q    N     3.399   123.306   119.800     0.179     0.000     2.598
   4    Q   HA     0.146     4.510     4.340     0.039     0.000     0.237
   4    Q    C    -2.091   173.967   176.000     0.097     0.000     0.914
   4    Q   CA    -0.234    55.623    55.803     0.092     0.000     1.065
   4    Q   CB     3.207    32.000    28.738     0.092     0.000     1.586
   4    Q   HN     0.131     8.504     8.270     0.173     0.000     0.484
   5    V    N     0.131   120.091   119.914     0.078     0.000     2.398
   5    V   HA     0.407     4.575     4.120     0.080     0.000     0.286
   5    V    C     0.162   176.322   176.094     0.109     0.000     1.026
   5    V   CA    -1.507    60.840    62.300     0.078     0.000     0.868
   5    V   CB     0.770    32.625    31.823     0.052     0.000     0.982
   5    V   HN     0.418     8.642     8.190     0.057     0.000     0.443
   6    L    N     7.083   128.385   121.223     0.130     0.000     2.123
   6    L   HA    -0.504     4.085     4.340     0.415     0.000     0.217
   6    L    C     1.827   178.814   176.870     0.195     0.000     1.081
   6    L   CA     3.308    58.271    54.840     0.205     0.000     0.772
   6    L   CB    -1.005    41.051    42.059    -0.005     0.000     0.890
   6    L   HN     0.241     8.694     8.230     0.097    -0.164     0.437
   7    A    N    -4.063   118.812   122.820     0.092     0.000     2.131
   7    A   HA    -0.337     4.023     4.320     0.067     0.000     0.220
   7    A    C     0.433   178.071   177.584     0.090     0.000     1.158
   7    A   CA     2.471    54.552    52.037     0.073     0.000     0.665
   7    A   CB    -0.332    18.690    19.000     0.036     0.000     0.795
   7    A   HN    -0.517     7.889     8.150     0.063    -0.219     0.460
   8    R    N    -4.310   116.247   120.500     0.096     0.000     2.191
   8    R   HA    -0.056     4.313     4.340     0.048     0.000     0.196
   8    R    C     2.152   178.488   176.300     0.060     0.000     0.991
   8    R   CA     1.349    57.485    56.100     0.060     0.000     1.075
   8    R   CB     0.834    31.147    30.300     0.023     0.000     1.040
   8    R   HN     0.244     8.408     8.270     0.109     0.172     0.526
   9    K    N     0.144   120.608   120.400     0.108     0.000     2.283
   9    K   HA    -0.130     4.148     4.320    -0.069     0.000     0.202
   9    K    C     0.691   177.214   176.600    -0.129     0.000     1.048
   9    K   CA     2.415    58.707    56.287     0.008     0.000     0.948
   9    K   CB    -0.114    32.430    32.500     0.074     0.000     0.742
   9    K   HN    -0.617     7.728     8.250     0.159     0.000     0.458
  10    W    N    -4.007   117.283   121.300    -0.016     0.000     2.846
  10    W   HA     0.195     4.850     4.660    -0.009     0.000     0.391
  10    W    C    -1.455   175.056   176.519    -0.013     0.000     1.011
  10    W   CA    -1.148    56.191    57.345    -0.011     0.000     1.832
  10    W   CB     0.166    29.622    29.460    -0.007     0.000     1.151
  10    W   HN    -0.634     7.728     8.180     0.377     0.045     0.582
  11    R    N     1.894   122.475   120.500     0.134     0.000     2.483
  11    R   HA    -0.096     4.293     4.340     0.083     0.000     0.329
  11    R    C    -1.368   174.959   176.300     0.045     0.000     0.961
  11    R   CA    -0.713    55.431    56.100     0.073     0.000     1.041
  11    R   CB     0.187    30.506    30.300     0.033     0.000     0.930
  11    R   HN    -0.880     7.272     8.270     0.107     0.182     0.413
  12    P   HA    -0.173     4.278     4.420     0.051     0.000     0.257
  12    P    C    -1.027   176.281   177.300     0.014     0.000     1.162
  12    P   CA     0.741    63.865    63.100     0.040     0.000     0.762
  12    P   CB     0.046    31.768    31.700     0.036     0.000     0.753
  13    Q    N     1.152   120.951   119.800    -0.001     0.000     2.396
  13    Q   HA     0.193     4.514     4.340    -0.032     0.000     0.220
  13    Q    C     0.275   176.261   176.000    -0.024     0.000     0.900
  13    Q   CA     0.394    56.181    55.803    -0.027     0.000     0.925
  13    Q   CB     2.516    31.223    28.738    -0.051     0.000     1.065
  13    Q   HN     0.012     8.472     8.270     0.002    -0.188     0.535
```

Comment: What is Sparta? What is this actually doing?

Comment: I added edits to address this. But its basically a text file with data, we extract the data we want and modify it based on user input (mutations to change specific letters, sequence to indicate the bounds), However my question here is to find another technique of using functions like this without having a bunch of entries.

Answer (score 1):

### Returns, not globals

Don't declare these at the global level:

```
sparta_file=()
sparta_directory=()
seq_file=()
seq_directory=()
```

Instead, return them from functions; e.g.

```
def input_file():
    fullpath = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, title='Choose a file')
    sparta_directory=os.path.dirname(fullpath)
    sparta_file= os.path.basename(fullpath)
    return sparta_directory, sparta_file
```

### Pathlib

Probably best to replace your use of `os.path` with `pathlib`, whose object-oriented interface is nicer to use.

### Local imports

such as

```
    from sparta_file_formatter import check_sparta_file_boundaries
```

should be moved to the top of the file.

Comment: Is there any advantage to not redefine them at the global level? It seems a little bit less clean since in my other script, I'd have to call the function in the argument I.E. some_function(input_file()), instead of some_function(input_file). And in some cases when I have multiple inputs, then I'll have multiple functions I'll be calling in as entries

Comment: Yes, there are many advantages. The fewer side-effects a function has, the better; and setting a global is a side-effect. Functions that accept parameters are easier to test, reuse, maintain and understand than functions that rely on globals.

Answer (score 1):

## Architecture

Your main architectural problem is that instead of

```
def make_a(params):
    return a

def make_b(a, params):
    return b

def make_c(b, params):
    return c

def make_result(c, params):
    return result

a = make_a(params_a)
b = make_b(a, params_b)
c = make_c(b, params_c)
result = make_result(c, params_result)
```

you do

```
def make_a(params):
    return a

def make_b(params_a, params_b):
    a = make_a(params_a)    
    return b

def make_c(params_a, params_b, params_c):
    b = make_b(params_a, params_b)
    return c

def make_result(params_a, params_b, params_c, params_result):
    c = make_c(params_a, params_b, params_c)
    return result

result = makeresult(params_a, params_b, params_c, params_result)
```

Instead of calling a function_1 to generate the necessary artefacts to pass to the next function_2 you call the function_1 inside function_2 and therefore you have to pass the requirements for function_2 as well.

In your case in function

```
def check_sparta_file_boundaries(seq_file,seq_directory,mutation_list1,mutation_list2,sparta_file,sparta_directory,seq_start):
    temp_list=[]
    temp_counter=0
    sparta_filtered_list=filter_sparta_using_seq(seq_file,seq_directory,mutation_list1,mutation_list2,sparta_file,sparta_directory,seq_start)
    for checker in sparta_filtered_list:
        temp_modifier=checker.strip()
        temp_split=temp_modifier.split()
        temp_finder=re.search('^\d+',temp_split[0])
        temp_list.append(temp_finder.group(0))
        temp_counter+=1
        if temp_counter==5:
            if int(temp_finder.group(0))==int(temp_list[0]):
                break
            else:
                del sparta_filtered_list[0:4]
                break
    if len(sparta_filtered_list)%6 != 0:
        del sparta_filtered_list[-5:-1]

    return sparta_filtered_list
```

you shall call `filter_sparta_using_seq` before calling `check_sparta_file_boundaries` and pass `sparta_filtered_list` instead of the parameters required for `filter_sparta_using_seq`

```
def check_sparta_file_boundaries(sparta_filtered_list):
    temp_list=[]
    temp_counter=0
    # line removed ...
    for checker in sparta_filtered_list:
        temp_modifier=checker.strip()
        temp_split=temp_modifier.split()
        temp_finder=re.search('^\d+',temp_split[0])
        temp_list.append(temp_finder.group(0))
        temp_counter+=1
        if temp_counter==5:
            if int(temp_finder.group(0))==int(temp_list[0]):
                break
            else:
                del sparta_filtered_list[0:4]
                break
    if len(sparta_filtered_list)%6 != 0:
        del sparta_filtered_list[-5:-1]

    return sparta_filtered_list

def main_program_flow():
    sparta_filtered_list = filter_sparta_using_seq(seq_file,seq_directory,mutation_list1,mutation_list2,sparta_file,sparta_directory,seq_start)
    sparta_filtered_list = check_sparta_file_boundaries(sparta_filtered_list)
```

Next you do the same for `filter_sparta_using_seq` and so on.

I tried to answer your specific question and hope you got the idea.

---

EDIT:

The same is valid for your function in the first file

```
def sparta_gen_only():
        from sparta_file_formatter import check_sparta_file_boundaries
        os.chdir(save_directory)
        with open(save_file_sparta,'w') as file:
            for stuff_to_write in check_sparta_file_boundaries(seq_file,seq_directory,mutation_list1,mutation_list2,sparta_file,sparta_directory,seq_start):
                file.write(stuff_to_write+'\n')
```

where you did not pass the parameters but act on globals. Again we do not call from the inside but call before and pass the results. Also we pass parameters instead of using globals.

```
def sparta_gen_only(sparta_filtered_list, directory_name, file_name):
    os.chdir(directory_name)
    with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
        for stuff_to_write in sparta_filtered_list:
            file.write(stuff_to_write + '\n')

def main_program_flow():
    sparta_filtered_list = filter_sparta_using_seq(seq_file,seq_directory,mutation_list1,mutation_list2,sparta_file,sparta_directory,seq_start)
    sparta_filtered_list = check_sparta_file_boundaries(sparta_filtered_list)
    sparta_gen_only(sparta_filtered_list, save_directory, save_file_sparta)
```

## some other points

- Get rid of the habit to change directory. At least for file read this is a no-go. Let the user determine the working directory.
- There is nothing wrong with fully qualified file names. You do not need to split to directory/basename.
- After restructuring your code according to the pattern above, there shall be no more globals

Comment: OH I see, so if I want to call the function and import its value, all I need to do is use it as an entry for the next function. The only issue is how do I use its value though in the next function. I assumed I'd need to redefine that value (that's why I do a=previous fun(previous entry) to use its values.